# How many forms vanish on the singular locus of a hypersurface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^3$ be a hypersurface of degree $d$ and let $Y$ be its singular locus. We assume that $Y$ has dimension $1$. Now let $V$ be the vector space of all forms of degree $d$ that vanish on $Y$. Is there any lower bound known on the dimension of $V$?

Clearly the product of any linear form with a derivative of the defining equation is in $V$. But I find it already hard to determine the dimension of the span of those.